# Installing gspread on OSX Anaconda for Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, gspread

I've tried a bunch of different variations of this out of the terminal and so far no joy. I'm trying to read Google Spreadsheets and would love to do it via Anaconda. Anaconda works great, but installing the gspread package so far is no joy. Here are some of the variations of what I've tried:

```
conda install gspread
```

This just results in `Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: gspread`

which makes me realize that route is probably just for stuff already available via Anaconda. So I tried downloading and unzipping gspread from here: [(gspread on github)](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

And then navigating to the folder `cd /Users/jlalonde/Downloads/gspread-master/gspread/`

And trying to install, via a bunch of different variations from there. Example:

```
conda install setup.py
```

...results in same error message:

```
Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: setup.py
```

So there may be a fast-and-easy way to do it, I'm just not using the right combination of commands to get it going. Here is hoping it is possible. Any Anaconda experts out there who can help? Maybe there is something other than gspread that is comparable? That would be OK, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with pip:

```
pip install gspread
```

Comment: Bizarrely, I thought I tried that, but I guess I didn't, because that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

pip and conda don't play well together

If you want to load using `conda`, run

`conda install -c conda-forge gspread`